# java Streams: collect taking in mind stream is empty

Tags: java, java-stream

I'd like to build a `Sort` object using this `Optional`-like code:

```
private Sort buildSort(Collection<String> fields) {
    fields.stream()
        .map(this::buildOrder)
        .collect(Sort.unsorted(), ????, ????);
}
```

`buildOrder` is:

```
private Order buildOrder(String field) {
    if (field.startsWith("-")) {
        return Order.desc(field.substring(1));
    }
    else {
        return Order.asc(field);
    }
}
```

I need to return an `Sort.unsorted()` if stream is empty, or combine each `Sort` object.

Sort object has an `and` method that stands for building and concatenate orders.

```
Sort.by(sort1)
    .and(sort2)...
```

So I need that:

```
if (stream is empty) then
  return Sort.unsorted
else
  return foreach item in stream:
     Sort.by(item).and(item2).and(item3)...
```

Classes:

```
org.springframework.data.domain.Sort
org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Order
```

**NOTE**

I need to use stream-api!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this should work. The second `map` converts each `Order` to it's own `Sort`. The accumulator and combiner then just add `Sorts` together.

```
return fields.stream()
    .map(this::buildOrder)
    .map(Sort::by)
    .collect(Sort::unsorted, Sort::and, Sort::and);
```

Comment: I'm getting `The type Sort does not define and(R, Sort) that is applicable here`. `Sort::and` is not a `BiConsumer` compliant. `and` method is `public Sort and(Sort sort) {...}`

Comment: It compiles just fine for me. I think you must have made some mistake when transcribing it. Potentially you left the first argument as `Sort.unsorted()` when it has actually changed to `Sort::unsorted`.

Answer (score 5):

As you need to use `Stream`s you can just use the this:

```
public Sort buildSort(Collection<String> fields) {
    return fields.stream()
        .map(this::buildOrder)
        .map(Sort::by)
        .reduce(Sort.unsorted(), Sort::and);
}
```

---

#### Old answer

As the `buildOrder()` method doesn't return an empty `Sort.Order` you can just initially check if `fields` is empty and then directly return a `Sort.unsorted()`.

And for the combining of the sorts you may not even want to use a `Stream` but rather a normal loop:

```
public Sort buildSort(Collection<String> fields) {
    if(fields.isEmpty()) {
        return Sort.unsorted();
    }

    Sort result = null;
    for(String field : fields) {
        Sort.Order order = buildOrder(field);
        if(result == null) {
           // initially create a Sort
           result = Sort.by(order);
        } else {
            // then just concatenate them
            result = result.and(order);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. you were right. I was using `collect` instead of `reduce`.

Comment: @Lino since `Sort.and` will return a new instance, Michael’s answer will *not* work at all, as it never produces anything other than `Sort.unsorted()` as result. It’s baffling that his answer got accepted. For immutable types, `reduce` is the right (if not only) approach. Though, I’d use `.reduce(Sort::and) .orElse(Sort.unsorted())` instead.

Comment: @Holger I am a bit baffled too, now that you mention it, thank you, I got the signatures of `reduce` and `collect` mixed up (I always do).

Comment: @Holger and I don't really like the `Optional<T> reduce()` method (I generally don't like `Optional`) but that's more an opinion than a fact ;)